# kafka ack=all and min-isr

Tags: apache-kafka

**Summary**

The docs and code comments for Kafka suggest that when the producer setting `acks` is set to `all` then an ack will only be sent to the producer when **all in-sync replicas have caught up**, but the code (`Partition.Scala`, `checkEnoughReplicasReachOffset`) seems to suggest that the ack is sent as soon as **min in-sync replicas have caught up**.

**Details**

The kafka docs have this:

> acks=all This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync replicas to acknowledge the record. 
>   [source](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

Also, looking at the Kafka source code - `partition.scala` `checkEnoughReplicasReachOffset()` has the following comment (emphasis mine):

> Note that this method will only be called if requiredAcks = -1 and we are waiting for **all replicas** in ISR to be fully caught up to the (local) leader's offset corresponding to this produce request before we acknowledge the produce request.

Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45783921/746754) on Stack Overflow (emphasis mine again)

> Also the min in-sync replica setting specifies the minimum number of replicas that need to be in-sync for the partition to remain available for writes. When a producer specifies ack (-1 / all config) it will still wait for acks from **all in sync replicas** at that moment (independent of the setting for min in-sync replicas).

But when I look at the code in Partition.Scala (note `minIsr < curInSyncReplicas.size`):

```
def checkEnoughReplicasReachOffset(requiredOffset: Long): (Boolean, Errors) = {
  ...
  val minIsr = leaderReplica.log.get.config.minInSyncReplicas
  if (leaderReplica.highWatermark.messageOffset >= requiredOffset) {          
    if (minIsr <= curInSyncReplicas.size)
      (true, Errors.NONE)
```

The code that calls this returns the ack:

```
if (error != Errors.NONE || hasEnough) {
  status.acksPending = false
  status.responseStatus.error = error
}
```

So, the code looks like it returns an ack as soon as the in-sync replica set are greater than min in-sync replicas. However, the documentation and comments suggest that the ack is only sent once all in-sync replicas have caught up. What am I missing? At the very least, the comment above `checkEnoughReplicasReachOffset` looks like it should be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Ismael on the jira-dev mailing list.

> The key point is the line:
>
> `if(leaderReplica.highWatermark.messageOffset >= requiredOffset) {`
>
> The high watermark only moves when all the replicas in ISR have that particular offset.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the mailing list?