# Kafka broker as a replica - but not register as an ISR

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to have a broker as a replica that never registers as an ISR (in-sync replica), even if it is in-sync.

I wish to have a broker (potentially in another data center) that replicates all partitions to a slower disk. The only reason for this broker to exist is for recovery purposes if all of the co-located ISRs fail at the same time - some data loss is acceptable.

Because of this: [kafka ack=all and min-isr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689177/kafka-ack-all-and-min-isr), I don't want this broker to register as an ISR, as it will increase the write-latency (either network/disk or both) of our idempotent producers because if the slower broker is in-sync when the write happens, it will wait for the ACK before confirming the write.

Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no it's not possible.

It sounds like you're looking at disaster recovery scenarios. Have you considered using something like [MirrorMaker](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#georeplication) to handle it?

With MirrorMaker, the target cluster is replicating data asynchronously and will not impact your producer latencies.

Comment: I'm looking for something that can automatically recover as much as it can (so much so that I have unclean leader election turned ON). My understanding of MirrorMaker is that is backs up to a separate cluster, but requires manual intervention to restore.