# follower replicas going out of sync in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with `partitions = 1` and `replication factor = 5`.
I started to publish messages on this topic. After few seconds, to my surprise, I observed that all followers were out of sync except the leader replica.

Before starting producer:

> Topic: log_compaction_topic4-15   Partition: 0    Leader: 5   Replicas: 5,1,2,3,4 Isr: 5,1,2,3,4

After starting producer:

> Topic: log_compaction_topic4-15   Partition: 0    Leader: 5   Replicas: 5,1,2,3,4 Isr: 5

Here, `min.insync.replicas=5` and the remaining topic configs have default values.
Also, my producer is publishing with `acks=1`

**Questions**

1. Why am I able to publish messages further, even though `mininsync.replicas=5`
2. Can I make all the followers to be in sync all the time?
3. Is this the expected behaviour? If yes, do I not loose some messages in case leader crashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why am I able to publish messages further, even though min.insync.replicas=5**

This configuration will be considered only when you set `acks="-1" or acks="all"`.

Kafka Official Doc says:

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), min.insync.replicas 
>   specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write
>   for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be 
>   met, then the producer will raise an exception (either 
>   NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend )

**Can I make all the followers to be in sync all the time?**

As mentioned above, you can achieve it by having `acks="-1" or acks="all"` and then mentioning `min.insync.replicas=5`.

**Is this the expected behaviour? If yes, do I not loose some messages in case leader crashes?**

Yes, in case leader fails you will lose messages. `acks=1` means that leader will write the record to its local log but will respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers. In this case should the leader fail immediately after acknowledging the record but before the followers have replicated it then the record will be lost.

**Question from comment:**

**But I observed difference in throughput between (acks=all, min.insync.replicas=1) and (acks=1). In acks=-1 setting, even though min.insync.replicas=1, leader is waiting for all in-sync replicas to acknowledge and hence lower throughput**

From [this answer on Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778455/kafka-rack-id-and-min-in-sync-replicas/45783921#45783921):

> Also the min in-sync replica setting specifies the minimum number of
>   replicas that need to be in-sync for the partition to remain available
>   for writes. When a producer specifies ack (-1 / all config) it will
>   still wait for acks from all in sync replicas at that moment
>   (independent of the setting for min in-sync replicas).

Also, [one of the useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778455/kafka-rack-id-and-min-in-sync-replicas/45783921#comment93887479_45783921):

> Just reconfirmed my answer with Jun (co-author of Apache Kafka). It is
>   a common misconception that min.insync.replicas allows an ACK when
>   only a minimal subset of the ISRs get the published message. However
>   the “minimum” part applies to something else. The minimal value is
>   defining how small the list of ISRs can get and still allow writes.
>   ACKs are always returned when all ISR in the list get the
>   message.Otherwise the leader election would be much more complicated
>   because not all replicas would actually be in sync.

Documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: "min.insync.replicas specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful". What if we set `acks=all`  and `min.insync.replicas=1` ? Is this same as setting `acks=1`?

Comment: Yes. It is same

Comment: But I observed difference in throughput between (`acks=all`, `min.insync.replicas=1`) and (acks=1). In `acks=-1` setting, even though `min.insync.replicas=1`, leader is waiting for all in-sync replicas to acknowledge and hence lower throughput.

Comment: That's weird. Let me check if I can find something useful.

Comment: @Markiv I have provided clarification for your doubt in Answer.

Comment: @Markiv Consider [accepting the answer if it helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)