# Kafka - min.insync.replicas interpretation

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the documentation looking at multiple places, it is adding up confusion..

About the property min.insync.replicas

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration
>   specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write
>   for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be
>   met, then the producer will raise an exception (either
>   NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend). When used
>   together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater
>   durability guarantees. A typical scenario would be to create a topic
>   with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and
>   produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises
>   an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write.

The questions I had,

1. Is this property had the meaning only if it is used with "acks" as part of "Sending the record" ( Producer) OR does it have any influence as part of the Consumer flow as well ?
2. What if  acks=all and min.insync.replicas = 1(default value :1 ) --> Is it same as acks = 1 ? ( considering replication-factor 3 ?

**Update #1**
I come across this [phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45783921/4242675)

"When a producer specifies ack (-1 / all config) it will still wait for acks from all in sync replicas at that moment (independent of the setting for min in-sync replicas). So if you publish when 4 replicas are in sync then you will not get an ack unless all 4 replicas commit the message (even if min in-sync replicas is configured as 2)."

how this phrase is relevant as of today ?Is this property "min in-sync replicas" still independent ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are two settings here that affect the producer:

- `acks` - this is a producer-level setting
- `min.insync.replicas` - this is a topic-level setting

The `acks` property determines how you want to handle writing to kafka:

`acks=0` - I don't care about receiving acknowledgment of receipt
[image: acks=0 illustration]

`acks=1` - Send an acknowledgment when the *leader* partition has received the batch in memory
[image: acks=1 illustration]

`all`/`-1` - Wait for **all** replicas to receive the batch before sending an acknowledgment 
[image: acks=all illustration]

Keep in mind, the receipt in the partition is *in memory*, Kafka by default doesn't wait for fsync to disk, so acks=1 is not a durable write!

`min.insync.replicas` is used when there is a problem in the topic, maybe one of the partitions is not in-sync, or offline. When this is the case the cluster will send an ack when `min.insync.replicas` is satisfied. So 3 replicas, with `min.insync.replicas=2` will still be able to write:
[image]

The acks property has no affect on the consumers, just that the data won't be written until `acks` and `min.insync.replicas` is satisfied.

> What if acks=all and min.insync.replicas = 1(default value :1 ) --> Is it same as acks = 1 ? ( considering replication-factor 3 ?

Only if there is a problem with the topic. If you have 3 replicas and `min.insync.replicas=1` and **two** of the partitions are down this is the same as acks=1. If the topic is healthy, the producer will wait for **all** replicas before sending the ack.

Comment: Does this mean -  "If the topic is healthy, the producer will wait for all replicas before sending the ack" - independent of the setting "min.insync.replicas"? Basically, i wanted to understand does "min.insync.replicas" have any impact on "Acks" setting ?

Comment: It only has an impact if in sync replicas < total number of replicas for the topic.

Comment: I just added update #1, can you please check and add your thoughts

Comment: @Nag, my answer covers your update #1, is there something that's not clear?

Comment: So , in summary - acks = all will send the acknowledgement if at least ""min.insync.replicas" responded back with the response. To quantify "atleast", it depends on the topic health. If all replicas(brokers) are functioning properly, ack will only be sent if all replicas are responds back with a response. IF not , atleast "min.insync.replicas" should respond back .

Comment: yep, looks like you got it

Comment: What happens to the consumer? If min.insync.replicas is 3 and ISR is 2, would the topic be available to consumers?

Comment: @viji Consumers will still be able to consume messages, the topic will not be unavailable, but producers will not be able to produce until min.isr in satisfied

Comment: @ChrisMatta when does the insync replica list gets updated in zookeeper, is it updated by the partition leader before sending the response to the producer (kafka 0.10.2)?

Comment: @Nag. I think you wrong in `If all replicas(brokers) are functioning properly, ack will only be sent if all replicas are responds back with a response.` My understanding that - If all replicas(brokers) are functioning properly, ack will only be sent as soon as `min.insync.replicas` are responded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580490/when-kafka-send-acknowledgement-if-acks-all-and-all-replicas-are-healthy

Comment: neat description. only question is whether for `ack=all` it checks for all replicas to be in sync or just the min ISR ones before the acknowledge back.