# When Kafka send acknowledgement if acks=all and all replicas are healthy?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

Let the Kafka producer is configured with `acks=all` and there are 5 broker replicas with `min.insync.replica=2` configuration.

I understand that if 3 brokers go offline, but 2 brokers are still up and healthy, then the producer will still get the message acknowledgement and will be able to continue sending the messages.

But what happens if all 5 brokers are up and healthy:

- #1 Will the producer receive the acknowledgement only after all 5 brokers write the message to themselves?
- #2 Or will the producer already receive the acknowledgement after 2 brokers write the message? So it will not wait for the feedback from the remaining other 3 brokers?

I am interesting in the throughput in the case when all broker replicas are healthy: will the throughput with `min.insync.replica=2` will be higher then with `min.insync.replica=5` (for `acks=all` and  5 broker replicas)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Producer will get the acknowledgement the moment data in written to `min.insync.replicas` that is 2 in this case. It will not wait for all brokers to get the message.
And yes, the throughput will definitely be higher when `min.insync.replica=2`

That is the tradeoff kafka is trying to give the user. If throughput is critical for you, keep `min.insync.replica` lower, but if reliability is more critical to you keep `min.insync.replica` higher.